# Align environment {amsmath} inside subfigure {subcaption} breaks figure numbering

Tags: numbering, amsmath, subcaption

When I put an equation in align environment into a subfigure, it breaks figure numbering. In the example below, the whole figure gets number 2, not 1 as I want.

How do I fix it?

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.6\linewidth}
\centering
% array* or flalign or similar here breaks numbering
\begin{flalign*}
a& = b \\
c& = d
\end{flalign*}
\subcaption{\label{fig:tb}}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{\label{fig:toffoli}Toffoli gate.}
\end{figure}
```

The example can be viewed at https://www.writelatex.com/read/xkhkknjnfvdq .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this by using

```
\[ \begin{aligned}
     %your equations
\end{aligned} \]
```

Here is a slight modification of your example: https://www.writelatex.com/read/gtnsxqnpkdtr

Comment: I'd use `$\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}$`: the centering is already provided.

Comment: Dear egreg, you are absolutely right. But maybe it would be even better to remove the `\centering`, and use the `\[ %stuff \]` to obtain normal displaymath. Don't you think so?

Comment: I'm not sure I would: `\[` can be dangerous when used first in a box. However, `subfigure` is a `minipage` under cover, so maybe it could work. I usually upvote questions I answer to (unless they are *really* unworthy).

Comment: Dear egreg, thanks for that bit of information. I did not know that!